# Is it possible by using ProcessBuilder to continuously interact with CLI program?

Tags: java, processbuilder

Basically I want to create an program that run on top of CLI program.
It will take input, execute it and show the output. And it should be interactive one.

Comment: Yes. Read the output of the process, display it to the user and/or do whatever else you need to, then write to the process. This will involve multiple threads.

Comment: Could you please give some basic implementation of it?
Because everywhere I got start process, run command in one go and process get close so I am not able to implement interactive one which I want

Comment: Well, actually, is your application already a CLI? If so, then you might get away with simply having the child process inherit its I/O (see `ProcessBuilder#inheritIO()`). If needed, make sure you block waiting for the child process to exit.

Comment: I tried that inheritIO, but it was not showing any output

Comment: Don't know what could be wrong as it worked for me. Maybe a [mre] would help?